# How to get a number from a string and then multiply the number?

Tags: python

I am currently unable to grab a digit from a number and multiply the digit. Here is my code:

```
Ask for the users INPUT
do they want to check an 8-digit number or generate a check digit from a 7-digit number?
print("Welcome to the Barcode Scanner. There are two options: ")
print("Do you want to check an 8-digit or generate a check digit from a 7 digit number?")
usersDecision = input("Press 7 to generate the 7th digit, or press 8 to check an 8 digit number")
Get the user to INPUT their 7 or 8 digit number
if usersDecision == "7":
print("You have chosen to generate a check digit from a 7 digit number?")
seven_digitCheck = input("Please enter your 7-digit number")

elif usersDecision == "8":
print("You have chosen to check the validity of an 8 digit number.")
eight_digitValid = input ("Please enter your 8 digit number")

else:
print("This is not a valid option, Please leave")
Get the first digit and MULTIPLY by 3 (this applies to both 7 and 8 digits)
```

Comment: the numbers i am using are 13245627 (hide the 8th digit fro the 8 digit checker option)

Comment: int() is the Python standard built-in function to convert a string into an integer value. You call it with a string containing a number as the argument, and it returns the number converted to an actual integer:

    print int("1234567")*3

Comment: Will that multiply the whole number??? I need only the first digit multiplied

Comment: Your code does nothing except input data. What it is supposed to do and what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need the solution below:

```
print("Welcome to the Barcode Scanner. There are two options: ")
print("Do you want to check an 8-digit or generate a check digit from a 7 digit number?")
usersDecision = input("Press 7 to generate the 7th digit, or press 8 to check an 8 digit number")

if usersDecision == "7":
    print("You have chosen to generate a check digit from a 7 digit number?")
    seven_digitCheck = input("Please enter your 7-digit number")

elif usersDecision == "8":
    print("You have chosen to check the validity of an 8 digit number.")
    eight_digitValid = input ("Please enter your 8 digit number")

else:
    print("This is not a valid option, Please leave")

multiply_1 = seven_digitCheck * 3

multiply_2 = eight_digitValid * 3

print "multiply_1: " + repr(multiply_1) + "\n"
print "multiply_2: " + repr(multiply_2) + "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

`eight_digitValid` or `seven_digitCheck`   is a string. So extract the first number, convert it into `int` and then multiply

```
first_digit = eight_digitValid [0]
numb = int(first_digit ) * 3
```